# URL Rewrite stopped working

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, sef

on joomla 3.3.6 some weird thing happened: the url's are not being rewritten to SEF. Everything is enabled and all. The weird thing is that the menus on site are rewriting their URL's and link to SEF as usual.

- I have updated to J3.4.1 (latest) to no avail..
- Checked htaccess - all good, and even changed with another from working site.

What else can I do?

Thanks

Comment: So the menus still work but the articles don't? Did you make any changes/installations to your site before it happened?

Comment: Thought about this, not that I remember. Moreover I have disabled all plugins and it didn't help. Still it might be something I forget, but I doubt that.